# Copy some properties into new constructor

Tags: c#, casting

I have a big class with a lot of properties (`BigClass`). I need to make a new class (`SmallClass`) with only some of those properties. This `SmallClass` must use all the overlapping properties from `BigClass`. What is the easiest way to do this without having to manually assign all the properties in the constructor of `SmallClass` like I do below:

```
class BigClass
{
    public int A { get; }
    public int B { get; }
    public int C { get; }
    public int D { get; }
    public int E { get; }

    public BigClass(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
        D = d;
        E = e;
    }
}

class SmallClass
{
    public int A { get; }
    public int B { get; }
    public int C { get; }

    public SmallClass(BigClass bigClass)
    {
        // I don't want to do all this manually:
        A = bigClass.A;
        B = bigClass.B;
        C = bigClass.C;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to do it at all?  Could `BigClass` inherit from `SmallClass` for instance? If not, and you do it with a loop using reflection etc, what would happen in the long run if both `BigClass` and `SmallClass` inadvertently gained the same property name, but used for completely unrelated purposes?

Comment: Please look at http://automapper.org/

Comment: I am a fan of AutoMapper as well

Comment: I'm a big anti-fan of automapper. It seems like a good idea, but I've found that it leads to code that's harder to maintain that doing such things "by hand".

Comment: What about using composition?  Could `BigClass` contain a `SmallClass`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper class:

```
public class Helper
{
    public static void CopyItem<T>(BigClass source, T target)
    {
        // Need a way to rename the backing-field name to the property Name ("<A>k__BackingField" => "A")
        Func<string, string> renameBackingField = key => new string(key.Skip(1).Take(key.IndexOf('>') - 1).ToArray());

        // Get public source properties (change BindingFlags if you need to copy private memebers as well)
        var sourceProperties = source.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(item => item.Name);
        // Get "missing" property setter's backing field
        var targetFields = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetField).ToDictionary(item => renameBackingField(item.Name));

        // Copy properties where target name matches the source property name
        foreach(var sourceProperty in sourceProperties)
        {
            if (targetFields.ContainsKey(sourceProperty.Key) == false)
                continue; // No match. skip

            var sourceValue = sourceProperty.Value.GetValue(source);
            targetFields[sourceProperty.Key].SetValue(target, sourceValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your SmallClass constructor:

```
public SmallClass(BigClass bigClass)
{
    Helper.CopyItem(bigClass, this);
}
```

This should work even if you only have property getters.

You can make CopyItem to work with all types by changing its declaration;

```
public static void CopyItem<U, T>(U source, T target)
```